# Помогите, как протестировать такое с помощью junit на котлине

Tags: kotlin, юнит-тесты, junit

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLocation() {

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation

            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "${location?.latitude}, ${location?.longitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                if (location == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "getLocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    getDataFromApi("Naryn")
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "getLocation()-> else statement ${location.latitude}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    getDataFromLatLon(location.latitude.toString(), location.longitude.toString())
                }

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failure Listenre: ${exception.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

    }
```

Comment: А, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: наверное, неправильно сформулировал вопрос, как протестить метод такого вида? В тестах разбираюсь плохо, нужно протестить эту функцию.

Comment: А, что именно Вы хотите протестить в этой функции?

Comment: функция находит текущее местоположение если юзер дал согласие на это(uses permission) , хочу убедиться в правильности. Если пользователь дал согласие и gps включен на девайсе то вызывает функцию, которая берет широту и долготу и делает запрос к базе. Если нет возвращает данные по умолчанию.